# Why is my program running faster on an older computer?

Tags: c#, performance, intel, 32-bit, amd-processor

I am using a 32 bit optimization program and a 32 bit simulation program for my project. The two program interact with each in the following manner. The optimization program generates random numbers, add them to an array, and send them to the simulation program. The simulation program opens a text file, read it, replace the random numbers, run the simulation, obtain performance values and send them back to the optimization software. The two program are connected through a dll file (that's how the optimization program works) that is coded in c# .Net Framework 3.5. I have been using these two programs for the past few years. On my older machine i7 3770 12 GB RAM, it is used to take 7 hours to do this cycle 100000 times. The CPU usage was on average 70% during the run.
Recently, I bought two computers i7 6770 16 GB RAM and AMD Ryzen 7 1700x 16 GB RAM. I assumed that these two computers would outperform the old one but I was wrong. Running exactly the same two programs for the same 100000 times took 11 hours and 14 hours; respectively. The CPU usage is less than 20% during the run.

I have used 4GB Patch by NTCore on both programs over the three machines. I am sure that the two new computers have more computational power than the old one but I cannot seem to find out why it is taking longer to run the programs. Any ideas?

Please keep in mind that I am not a programmer nor a computer/software engineer, so I would appreciate it if you can be thorough and patient.

Comment: Is everything else the same (e.g. SSDs vs Disks, same type of RAM, number of RAM chips)? The 2 Intel chips have basically the same amount of processing power. The AMD has more, but it does that by having more cores. The 3 chips actually have the same speed per core. Having said that, if everything else is the same then I can't explain it taking longer.

Comment: Well it all depends on what your code is and what hardware it is. Like if it's multi-threaded it could have to do with how the work is shared by its cores.

Comment: @ Greg: None of them have SSD. The newer computers have a larger hard disk. The older machine had DDR3 while the new ones have DDR4. The old one had 4 4 GB RAM while the new ones have 2 8 GB RAM. What do you mean by the same type of RAM and number of RAM chips? The older machine had Windows 7 Enterprise while the i7 6700 has WIndows 7 Pro and the AMD has Windows 10 Pro. Based on my research the operating system won't impact the performance.

Comment: @ Bauss: The code and program are single threaded. Do you think the .Net Framework used (3.5) would be slower on newer computers?

Comment: @Newbie82 i7 3770 has 8 virtual cores. If the programs are single threaded, how come it can consume 70% CPU on i7 3770? One single threaded program can only consume, in theory, 12.5% of CPU on a 8 core computer.

Comment: @ Xiaoguo: I do not know. I am sure it is single threaded though.

Comment: It does look single threaded on your new computers though. 2 program consume 20% of the CPU time(10% each). And the numbers makes sense, CPU usage dropped from 70% to 20%. Slightly more than half. Overall time taken about doubled.

Comment: It is hard to tell exactly the specs on your processors, but there are a few factors: some processors are made for mobile and run at slower speeds to reduce power consumption.  The size of the instruction cache can also play a role as well as any on-board FGPU etc.  The motherboard buildout and chipset can also play a role.  You may have options to tune some settings through BIOS.

Comment: @ Nathan: The three processors are on workstations. The old one is HP z220, while the new ones are Dell Optiplex (intel) and CyperPower Gaming PC (AMD). How can I check the size of the instruction cache? I know the CyperPower allows for some tweaking but I doubt it will reduce the computation time by half to match at least the old one.

Comment: @ Xiaoguo: I might be mistaken about the 70%. It has been a couple of years. I just checked the CPU usage for each one. the optimization program uses 0.1% while the simulation program uses 7%. The simulation program version that I am using now was built in 2016 while the previous one in 2014. There is no difference between the two builds. They even have the same version number. The new build was necessary since the main developer of the program passed away and his partner had to come up with a new build so that the program do not connect to the server to check for program license.

Comment: There are more things you can check beside CPU usage. What is the Disk usage on all three systems. When the new program are built, are the settings different than it was originally built(e.g. debug, release, any parameter tweaks). I assume the operating systems are different. Also, the .net framework versions are also different.

Comment: In addition to disk usage (and yes, a larger drive often is slower) the network speed can also wigh in. As do optimized drivers, AV software etc..

Comment: @ Xiaoguo: I do not have access to the old computer. I just checked the CyberPower and it is less the 2%. The avg. write speed is around 60 kb/s. The program requires  Microsoft Visual C++ 2008 SP1 Redistributable Package (x86) to be installed. It has been the same requirement since day 1. The i7 6700 has Windows 7 Pro and it is faster than the amd one which has Windows 10 Pro. The old machine had Windows 7 Enterprise.

Comment: @ TaW: I will buy SSD tomorrow and try if it will improve the performance. The computers are brand new and they have no other programs installed on them. Is there a way to know how much CPU a process can handle? What is the maximum CPU allocation can be given to one process?

Comment: What is the disk usage? There may also be different caching methods at work.. How large or small are the files? Large HDs tend to have much larger cluster sizes..

Comment: The i7 3770 actually has a much higher base frequency(3.4G) than 6770 (2.6G). It is very likely that 3770 is faster than 6770. Based on your description, the program are not using the full power of the CPU. If you really need the speed, probably it is time to hire someone to adapt the program. There is a 4 fold performance increase potential on a single machine.

Comment: @ Xiaoguo: They both have 3.4 G. The adaptation will start in September, and I wanted to use during the summer.

Comment: @ TaW: the disk usage is less than 2% at most. The file size is pretty small (< 1MB).

Comment: @XiaoguoGe: Max turbo is what matters; unless a single-threaded program is using SIMD, it can probably sustain max turbo if nothing else is running.  But the key here is that "i7 6770" doesn't exist. Presumably they actually have an "i7 6770HQ" laptop CPU.   (https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/93341/intel-core-i76770hq-processor-6m-cache-up-to-3-50-ghz.html), 4c8t turbo up to 3.50 GHz, 6 MiB of L3 cache. vs. [i7 3770](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/65719/intel-core-i73770-processor-8m-cache-up-to-3-90-ghz/specifications.html) 4c8t up to 3.9 GHz, 8 MiB L3

Comment: On some workloads, the Skylake laptop probably is faster despite the lower frequency vs. the older desktop, if memory bandwidth and/or L2 cache bandwidth is a factor, along with general improvements that give SKL higher instructions per clock than IVB.  If the code can take advantage of AVX2 for 256-bit integer SIMD, SKL has a big advantage.  But Ivy Bridge is not a bad architecture; it's not that far behind in per-clock performance on most code.

Comment: Try running multiple instances of the optimization and simulation program on the newer hardware. If the software is programmed such that only one instance can run at a time, try building multiple virtual machines on the newer hardware. Almost certainly, the programs are single threaded.

Comment: Check your power scheme. Set it to `High Performance` or similar. Modern computers are often configured to save power whenever they can. Also, check if the `SMT` (Simultaneous Multithreading) bios setting differs between the laptops.